# web application hosted in IIS throws Gateway Timeout error

Tags: .net, iis

I have some web applications hosted in IIS in port 80 with the different hostname in Windows Server 2016. When I browse these within the server it works fine. But if I try to access these applications outside server it throws Gateway timeout error without any error code. 
But if I ping the URL no packets lost. Is this IIS issue? What is the setting that is blocking it? Firewall is not turned on. Sites are not blocked.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: One of reason may be your firewall. You should check your firewall open on port 80 or not

Comment: "The access is unrestricted.
I can telnet port 80 to sites and it works fine.
There is definitely no access issue to the server 
You might need to check the webserver logs to identify what is going on." This is the reply we got from server team. When i check logs it show me some unrelated issues with cortana.

Comment: Do you have a binding listening on the correct port? Are you using the correct URL? is IIS up and running when you test from outside?

Comment: Yes, all the 7 applications are in port 80 and bindings are also correct. URL are also correct. IIS is up and Running but test form outside gives timeout error.

Comment: Did you check if you arrive to IIS, did you check logs? You can also enable Request Tracing for more detail (if you arrive to the server)..